# Check a radio button by default (unmapped ChoiceType field)

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to have one of the options of a ChoiceType field selected by deafult using Symfony's FormBuilder.

I found a lot of similar questions, but most are about a field mapped to an entity, which is not my case here. The other answers I found involved using the "data" or the "empty_data" attribute, none of which seem to work for me.

Here's my current "add" method (in my FormBuilder):

```
$builder->add('type2', ChoiceType::class, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'label' => false,
    'choices' => [
        "Incoming" => ComEntry::INCOMING,
        "Outgoing" => ComEntry::OUTGOING,
    ],
    'expanded' => true,
    'empty_data' => 'Incoming',
]);
```

(I also tried with `'empty_data' => ComEntry::INCOMING,`.)

When rendering the form, no radio box is selected, what I would like is to have the first one ("Incoming") selected by default.

Thanks by advance for any reply :-)

EDIT : Here's what I used in the end (instead of `'empty_data' => 'Incoming',`), because type2 is a subset of type (type is a sum of bits, type2 is a choice between the `INCOMING` and the `OUTGOING` bits).

````
'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value) use ($options) {
    // If the record is being edited and the user selected "Outgoing" at creation, check the "Outgoing" choice.
    if($options['data']->getType() & ComEntry::OUTGOING and $choice == ComEntry::OUTGOING)
        return ['checked' => 'checked'];
    // Else, check the "Incoming" choice.
    elseif($choice == ComEntry::INCOMING)
        return ['checked' => 'checked'];
    else
        return [];
},```
````

Comment: Did you tried with `'empty_data' => ['Incoming'],` since you are using `'expanded' => true,` ?

Comment: @Tib I just tried, but it doesn't seem to work either. `multiple` is implicitly set to `false` though, I would guess `'empty_data' => array(...)` is more for checkboxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [`choice_attr`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr) option in its callable form:

> This can be an associative array where the keys match the choice keys
>   and the values are the attributes for each choice, a callable or a
>   property path.

```
'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value) use ($options) {
    // If no value is set mark INCOMING as checked
    if (empty($options['data']->type2) && ComEntry::INCOMING == $value) {
        return ['checked' => 'checked'];
    }
    return [];
},
```

Comment: I love the idea, but it doesn't seem to work. `$choice` contains the value of the choice (so `ComEntry::INCOMING`, an integer), while `$value` contains the same value as a string. So for the first reason, `$choice` is never empty.

Comment: @Saphir I mixed `key` and `value`, that's fixed now. I'm passing the `$options` array so you can access `data`. I gather you only want to do this if the field is empty, right?

Comment: This gives me a "Cannot use object of type App\Entity\Mysql\ComEntry as array" exception. Though `type2` is unmapped, the other fields in the form still use an object as data.

Comment: @Saphir So your `FormType` has an object `data_class`. Depending on the visibility you will have to use a getter instead of accessing `->type2` directly. I made one further correction with the `return [];`

Comment: I know my class is a little weird, sorry :D
My `FormType` uses a ComEntry object as data, but this object only has a `type` attribute, not a `type2` attribute. I want the `type2` to be computed separately from the object in the controller, hence why it's unmapped.

Comment: @Saphir So `type2` is going to always be empty. Can you describe what you want to do in more detail? I don't think you can do this in the form type itself, but in a listener or the controller.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I thought it'd work, but you're right, it's going to always be empty. I managed to do exactly what I want using the closure you gave me though (with `use ($options)`), so thank you for that.
Basically, `INCOMING` and `OUTGOING` are two bits of the `type` attribute, so I have a select box to choose one bit among four, these radio buttons to choose one bit among two others, and I have a checkbox for another optional bit.
I'll mark your answer as accepted and I'll edit my first post with what I used in the end. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is : `'data' => ComEntry::INCOMING` instead of the `empty_data`

The `empty_data` is useful when the form is submitted.

**But** this method will work only for creation. For the edition you will have to check if the form has been initialized with data.

Comment: I thought of that one and it work, but I'd like to use it as a last resort, because I'd like to use the same controller for both creation and edition. Thanks for your reply though.